# JS access to mongoengine backend

Tags: javascript, mongodb, flask, eve

I have a model created with `Mongoengine` and `Python` but need to access this data from JS for visualization on a `Flask web app`. What's the best way to do this?

I know of `Python Eve` and `eve-mongoengine` but it feels like creating a rest interface just for JS access is a bit too heavy. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to make a full rest api. Just create a route that will return a JSON. Use Flask's `jsonify` and `GET` the JSON using `axios`, `fetch`, `jQuery`or whatever you like.

Example using `axios`:

```
# app.py
# import jsonify from Flask
...
@app.route('/data')
def return_json():
    # query = you query
    return jsonify(query)
```

Remember to add `axios` to you static files or use a CDN.

```
// main.js
var axios = require('axios');

axios.get('/data')
  .then(function (response) {
    // do something with your data
   })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle errors, like console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: That's a lot more elegant. Thanks!